# Get request in openshift node js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I'm building an openshift node js app which has to communicate with youtube data API. Its deployment is a success when I do "git push" with the require commented.

```
    /*
    var request = require('request');
    */
```

When I uncomment it, I get this error :

```
remote: Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...
remote: Application 'eln' failed to start (port 8080 not available)
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 573c3e177628e146d400004e (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/573c3e177628e146d400004e/nodejs
```

Am I doing it bad? How can I fix it?

thank you.

Edit 1: Adding listening code, I didn't modify it (it was already here when I've created the app).

```
    self.ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
    self.port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

    /**
     *  Start the server (starts up the sample application).
     */
    self.start = function()
    {
        //  Start the app on the specific interface (and port).
        self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function()
        {
            console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...', Date(Date.now() ), self.ipaddress, self.port);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Is your application listening on any port? If yes, then show me your code of listen method

Comment: Added in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my `app.js` basic code that is working on openshift.

```js
#!/bin/env node

ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;

if (typeof ipaddress === "undefined") {
    //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
    //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
    console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
    ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
};

var server = app.listen(8080, ipaddress, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Can you try that?

**Update**

After trying it on openshift with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) I also got this error but it was because `package.json` didn't have `request` under dependencies.

My dependencies now look like this and it works fine:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "request": "latest" // this is added
  },
```

Comment: It works. But as soon I add the require i need (var request = require('request')), it can't be deployed because of this port issue.

Comment: I tried request locally and it's working fine, did you tried it locally? Later I'll try it on openshift and let you know if I get same error.

Comment: My code works well locally, but don't work when I deploy it on openshift.